# Javascript/Jquery - Hide div & it's children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through the array of div elements & trying to hide it along with it's children `div

```
function hideDivEle(divList) {
    if (divList.Length === '') {
        // Some code to restore all the div's back
    } else {
        // Hide all the required divs
        for (var i = 0; i < divList.length; i++) {
           // $(divList[i]).hide().fadeIn(450);
                $(divList[i]).css('display','none');           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls submit your HTML as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the correct selector, [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you need to prefix it with `#` and for [Class Selector](http://Class%20Selector%20(%E2%80%9C.class%E2%80%9D)) prefix it with `.`

Assuming you intent to use [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), use the following code

```
$('#' + divList[i]).hide(); //Simple use hide() instead of .css('display','none')
```